# 404 while trying to fetch sheet data as json

Tags: google-sheets-api

I'm trying to load my sheet contents by calling it as a json endpoint.

```
fetch("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/MYSHEETID/1/public/values?alt=json")
                
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(json => {
                    const data = [] /* this array will eventually be populated with the contents of the spreadsheet's rows */
```

I'm using the method described at https://benborgers.com/posts/google-sheets-json

It works about 30% of the time and I get a 404 the other 70% of the time. I've been struggling with it for days and can't figure out why it's failing.

Comment: I have also been getting this error multiple times today... I have added console logging to the app to track and output the result of `fetch` and am noticing that SOMETIMES it works, sometimes not. Perhaps an issue on Google's end? (I am not in a position to build a debugging test for this right now, so cannot confirm that)

Comment: Can you provide the entire code?

Answer (score 1):

I changed to the API V4, but I noticed the author of the link you provided updated the code.

https://benborgers.com/posts/google-sheets-json

```
const spreadsheetId = '...'
fetch(`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${spreadsheetId}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json`)
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(text => {
        const json = JSON.parse(text.substr(47).slice(0, -2))
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to share your spreadsheet to at least allow everyone to read. Then

```
function getJson(id,gid){
  var txt = UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${id}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json&tq&gid=${gid}`).getContentText();
  var jsonString = txt.match(/(?<="table":).*(?=}\);)/g)[0]
  var json = JSON.parse(jsonString)
  return(json)
}
```

- with id of the spreadsheet and gid of your sheet (may be 0)
- note that first row is dedicated to labels, then rows[0] corresponds to row#2 and c[0] corresponds to column A
- if you want to retrieve B1 (column 2 row 1) : `json.cols[1].label`
- if you want to retrieve B2 (column 2 row 2) : `json.rows[0].c[1].v`

Answer (score 0):

json feed is the older version of Sheets API and it's shut down. See Google's announcement here https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/g-suite/migrate-your-apps-use-latest-sheets-api