# How do I fetch Google Spreadsheet data from Javascript in Sheets v4 API as JSON?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-api

Below is how I attempted to fetch data from Google Sheets.
However, this method seems to be deprecated in Sheets V4 API.
It was no longer working.
There might be other ways to get the data from Google Sheet.

```
var url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1hA4LKZn9yKoqnSzaI6_73GQSj_ZVpB3O0kC93QM98Vs/od6/public/basic?alt=json";
$.ajax({
    url:url,
    dataType:"jsonp",
    success:function(data) {
        // data.feed.entry is an array of objects that represent each cell
    },
});
```

How do I fetch Google Spreadsheet data from Javascript in Sheets v4 API as JSON?

Comment: Change `dataType:"jsonp"` to `dataType:"json"`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But the same 404 error happens.

Comment: If `https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1hA4LKZn9yKoqnSzaI6_73GQSj_ZVpB3O0kC93QM98Vs/od6/public/basic?alt=json` gives a 404. Do you have access to the document?

Comment: Modify the url as recommended below

Answer (score 2):

`feeds` is deprecated in V4. See this post [404 while trying to fetch sheet data as json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68796548/404-while-trying-to-fetch-sheet-data-as-json/68845761#68845761)

```
function getJson(id,gid){
  var txt = UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${id}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json&tq&gid=${gid}`).getContentText();
  var jsonString = txt.match(/(?<="table":).*(?=}\);)/g)[0]
  var json = JSON.parse(jsonString)
  return(json)
}
```

- with id of the spreadsheet and gid of your sheet (may be 0)
- note that first row is dedicated to labels, then rows[0] corresponds to row#2 and c[0] corresponds to column A
- if you want to retrieve B1 (column 2 row 1) : json.cols[1].label
- if you want to retrieve B2 (column 2 row 2) : json.rows[0].c[1].v

Comment: If this has already been answered, surely mark it as a duplicate?

Comment: maybe, my answer must be adapted to jQuery and ajax ... so I'll leave that for a while waiting for the opinion of EI Joier

Comment: Hi @MikeSteelson. This is very helpful. I would like to know the document that describes these indexes, such as 'gvix', 'tq', 'tqx', and 'gid'.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know exactly ... I use only this syntax `/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json&tq` in my projects ! What I can say is, as output format you can use `tqx=out:csv` `tqx=out:html` `tqx=out:json` (to be verified/tested), and tq can be associated with a query `tq={query}` ... if you find anything in the documentation, pls tell me.

Comment: oh, I found it. That might be helpful. https://ai2.metricrat.co.uk/guides/use-gviz-to-get-and-query-google-sheet-data